# ClassNotFoundException on static inner class

Tags: java, reflection

I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException` using `Class.forName()` passing the fully qualified name of a public static class that lives inside the same package. This is when running my tests.

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)
    at com.badlogic.ashley.serialization.EntitySerializerTests.read(EntitySerializerTests.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

In `EntitySerializerTests.java` inside my `tests` folder.

```
package com.badlogic.ashley.serialization;
public class EntitySerializerTests {

    public static class TestComponentA implements Component {
        public int value;
    }

    ...
}
```

In my library code

```
package com.badlogic.ashley.serialization;
public class EntitySerializer implements Json.Serializer<Entity> {
    ...

    private Component read(Json json, JsonValue componentValue) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String className = componentValue.name();
        Class componentType = Class.forName(className); // THROWS
        ...
    }
}
```

The exception message is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.ashley.serialization.EntitySerializerTests.TestComponentA
```

Library code is trying to get the `Class` given the name for a class that's defined in a test file. Is that allowed? I would assume that, at runtime, all these classes are available in the class path.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Can I at least get a reason why?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should ALWAYS post the full stack trace of the exception when asking about an exception. It's also unclear if you're executing a test, or production code. The stack trace would help finding that out. If you're executing production code, why would the test classes be in the classpath?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for helping me improve my question. I've clarified that this happens when running tests and linked to the full stacktrace.

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't show any ClassNotFoundException. So, you're asking about a ClassNotFoundException, but posting the stack trace of another one. That is not helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the class name for reflection is not `com.badlogic.ashley.serialization.EntitySerializerTests.TestComponentA`, it is `com.badlogic.ashley.serialization.EntitySerializerTests$TestComponentA` (`$` instead of `.` to separate the inner class from the enclosing class).

You can also check this if you look at the filename of the compiled class or with `EntitySerializerTests.TestComponentA.class.getName()`.